# When i use transform translate than my border height increase more 1px how to solve it?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I wast try to set **1px separator** with vertically center using **transform: translate(-50%, -50%);** and **top: 50%;** but working fine for vertically center but my separator height increase with 1px more so my separator **total height display 2px** so any solution for that issues. this structure is fixed so please help me.

**Thanks in adavance.**

```css
.number {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.title {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.separator-line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(100% + 15px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row my-5">
        <div class="col-3 text-center px-3">
          <div class="position-relative mb-4">
              <span class="separator-line"></span>
              <div class="number">01</div>
          </div>
          <span class="d-block title mb-3">Completed Project</span>
          <p class="px-4">Lorem ipsum is simply text of the printing typesetting Lorem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center px-3">
            <div class="position-relative mb-4">
                <span class="separator-line"></span>
                <div class="number">02</div>
            </div>
            <span class="d-block title mb-3">Completed Project</span>
            <p class="px-4">Lorem ipsum is simply text of the printing typesetting Lorem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center px-3">
            <div class="position-relative mb-4">
                <span class="separator-line"></span>
                <div class="number">03</div>
            </div>
            <span class="d-block title mb-3">Completed Project</span>
            <p class="px-4">Lorem ipsum is simply text of the printing typesetting Lorem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center px-3">
            <div class="position-relative mb-4">
                <div class="number">04</div>
            </div>
            <span class="d-block title mb-3">Completed Project</span>
            <p class="px-4">Lorem ipsum is simply text of the printing typesetting Lorem.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: try ``` transform: translateX(-50%);  in .separator-line``` class. If it helps.

Comment: Firefox works fine, any specific browser?

Comment: @Lalji Tadhani yes Firefox working fine but chrome doesn't working increase 1px more height.

Comment: Thank you very much Prakhar Mittal this is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change CSS use This `transform: translateX(-50%);` for `.separator-line`

```css
.number {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.title {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.separator-line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(100% + 15px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row my-5">
        <div class="col-3 text-center px-3">
          <div class="position-relative mb-4">
              <span class="separator-line"></span>
              <div class="number">01</div>
          </div>
          <span class="d-block title mb-3">Completed Project</span>
          <p class="px-4">Lorem ipsum is simply text of the printing typesetting Lorem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center px-3">
            <div class="position-relative mb-4">
                <span class="separator-line"></span>
                <div class="number">02</div>
            </div>
            <span class="d-block title mb-3">Completed Project</span>
            <p class="px-4">Lorem ipsum is simply text of the printing typesetting Lorem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center px-3">
            <div class="position-relative mb-4">
                <span class="separator-line"></span>
                <div class="number">03</div>
            </div>
            <span class="d-block title mb-3">Completed Project</span>
            <p class="px-4">Lorem ipsum is simply text of the printing typesetting Lorem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center px-3">
            <div class="position-relative mb-4">
                <div class="number">04</div>
            </div>
            <span class="d-block title mb-3">Completed Project</span>
            <p class="px-4">Lorem ipsum is simply text of the printing typesetting Lorem.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```